# Add Dom Elements Dynamically to Prerendered Angular2 Universal Page

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-universal

I'm recently switched to angular2 universal to make my SPA crawled by search engine and Angular Universal is awesome for doing this use case, I got into problem when I tried to inject for each page dynamic meta data, I tried to use ElementRef With Renderer, and I used some [angular2-meta](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/src/angular2-meta.ts) service but it doesn't work when platform not Browser

The Code Following is My Latest Attempt

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, Renderer, Inject, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DomRenderer ,NodeDomRenderer} from 'angular2-platform-node';
import {isBrowser, isNode } from 'angular2-universal';
import { Meta, MetaDefinition } from '../../services/meta.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor(public meta:Meta) {
        const name: MetaDefinition = {name: 'application-name', content: 'Name of my application'};                
    const desc: MetaDefinition = {name: 'description', content: 'A description of the page'};
    const tags: HTMLMetaElement[] = this.meta.addTags([name, desc]);
    }
}
```

When I wrap the code in constructor with 
    `if(isBrowser)` it rendered only in client side but when I view source code of page it doesn't rendered

When I tried render with renderer `the this.renderer.createElement` function doesn't work

Are there any solutions or ideas to make meta tags rendered in server before page sent to client, I'm using **angular universal** with **ASP.NET Core 1.1**

Thanks in advance